# Load an AWS instance upon local windows booting up

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, startup

Our company in moving into Amazon WorkSpaces.  We all currently have normal desktop computers winning Windows 7.  There are a couple of us who will need local windows and will also be working in the WorkSpace.  There are others who will only need to work in there Amazon WorkSpace environment.  Is there a way to automatically boot the workspace instance upon windows loading and then when the instance is closed it will shut down windows.  Essentially denying those users access to the local copy of windows.

Would also need a way for an administrator to access the local Windows..

Thanks

Comment: [How to Easily Put a Windows PC into Kiosk Mode With Assigned Access](http://www.howtogeek.com/173562/how-to-easily-put-a-windows-pc-into-kiosk-mode-with-assigned-access/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what i am trying to do is available in a function that Windows provides.  I will look into the functionality of the "Kiosk" function that is available in Windows 7.